# Webview always load not exist url

Tags: android, webview

i have a problem here.

I use webview to load a url(e.g. www.example.com/yyy) in my app, but whenever I do the 'load' action, 
there is always another 'load' action try to load the favicon(the url is www.me.com/favicon.ico) of the website. Which will return a 404 not found error.

Is this(loading favicon) a default behavior of webview? how can i disable it?

Below is the header of the send request.

```
    GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
   Host: xxx.com
   Pragma: no-cache
   Cache-Control: no-cache
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/MMB29Q; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/48.0.2564.106       Mobile Safari/537.36

   Referer: http://www.example.com/k.gif?yd_ewp=498&yd_ext=EnQKATASIDM0YzZkNjE3MjcyNjI1N2I0N2FiMjIxZWM1Mzc5MmZkIksIxJSRCBDw5P8BGPKzHiC1_RAo8k4wZDhkZQAA-UNwAHgAgAEAmAEBogELVHJhZGl0aW9uYWy6ARJ7Ik9SREVSRURfSUQiOiIxIn0wAiIkOTI5NDM4MDMtZjFiOS00NGUyLTkwZjgtYzgwNmE2YmU5OWUyKG4wADoAQgBSDzExNC4yMTUuMTI5LjEyNWoNMTQ1ODAxMjg1MjkxOHgAggEAiAHyA5ABtqXawrcqqAEBsAEBuAEBwgEDOTY4yAEB0AEB2gEPMzU4MjM5MDU3NjEyMzYw
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Accept-Language: zh-CN,en-US;q=0.8
   X-Requested-With: com.you
```

the code is a very simple use of webview:

```
        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                        String description, String failingUrl) {
                loadNext(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                loadNext(view);
            }

            private void loadNext(WebView view){
                mIndex++;
                if(mIndex < mUrlSize){
                    try {
                        view.loadUrl(mUrls[mIndex]);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    stopSelf();
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: This URL redirects to `icloud`

Answer (score 0):

One quick fix for that is to override the `getFavicon()` function in your custom `WebView`. Just override that function. It should return a `Bitmap` object, so you can return any dummy Bitmap.

Comment: it doesn't work, still call the www.example.com/favicon.ico

Comment: Did you call `super()` in the override function? @Luis404